# Cant get collisions to work for Mario-like game

Tags: processing, collision-detection

so, I've spent a fair few hours on my Mario-like game but recently I've been stuck on the collisions after I changed to an object based collision system that seems like it should work but there is a bug somewhere that i cant find.

currently the box that represents the player just falls straight through the platform rather than sitting on the platform

You wont be able to run this snippet because I'm new to stack overflow and couldn't find anything closer to processing.

Here is the box class that has all my collision detection

```js
//Box class -- THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP -- everything else is just for context

//Box class

class Box {
  private float xpos, ypos, sizeX, sizeY;
  private float bottom = ypos + sizeY;
  private float top = ypos;
  private float left = xpos;
  private float right = xpos + sizeX;
  Box(float startX, float startY, float xSize, float ySize) {
    boxes++;
    xpos = startX;
    ypos = startY;
    sizeX = xSize;
    sizeY = ySize;
  }
  void update() {
    rect(xpos, ypos, sizeX, sizeY);
  }
  void collision() {
    //If on box level
    if (player.playerY + player.playerHeight >= top && player.playerY <= bottom) {

      //Left Side
      if ((player.playerX + player.playerWidth) <= left && (player.playerX + player.playerWidth) + speed >= left) {
        player.playerX = left - player.playerWidth;
        player.canMoveRight = false;
      }
      //Right Side
      if (player.playerX >= right && player.playerX + speed <= right) {
        player.playerX = right;
        player.canMoveLeft = false;
      }
    }

    //If in box Y coord
    if (player.playerX + player.playerWidth >= left && player.playerX <= right) {
      //top
      if (player.playerY + player.playerHeight <= top && player.playerY + player.yVelocity + gravity >= top) {
        player.Gravity = false;
        player.playerY = top - player.playerHeight;
        player.yVelocity = 0;
        player.canMoveDown = false;
      }
      //bottom
      if (player.playerY + player.yVelocity >= bottom && player.playerY + player.yVelocity + gravity <= bottom) {
        player.canMoveUp = false;
        player.yVelocity = 0;
        player.playerY = bottom;
      }
    }
    //onGround
    if (player.playerY == ypos - player.playerHeight) {
      player.onGround = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Control structure for multiple keypresses

```js
//Control structure to enable multiple keypresses

//Control

float speed = 4;
float gravity = 1;
float jump = 10;

boolean isUp, isLeft, isDown, isRight;


void control() {
  //Controls
  if (isUp) {
    if (player.canMoveUp) {
      if (player.onGround) {
        player.Gravity = true;
        player.yVelocity = 0 + jump;
        player.onGround = false;
      }
    }
  }
  if (isDown) {
    if (player.canMoveDown) {

    }
  }
  if (isRight) {
    if (player.canMoveRight) {
      player.playerX += speed;
    }
  }
  if (isLeft) {
    if (player.canMoveLeft) {
      player.playerX -= speed;
    }
  }
  if (player.onGround) {
    player.Gravity = false;
    player.yVelocity = 0;
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  setMove(keyCode, true);
}

void keyReleased() {
  setMove(keyCode, false);
}

boolean setMove(int k, boolean b) {
  switch (k) {
    case UP:
      return isUp = b;

    case DOWN:
      return isDown = b;

    case LEFT:
      return isLeft = b;

    case RIGHT:
      return isRight = b;

    default:
      return b;
  }
}
```

Main tab, box/entity updates and player class

```js
//Main tab
float boxes = 0;
//Calls classes

Box b = new Box(0, 700, 800, 100);
Box b1 = new Box(300, 675, 25, 25);

Player player = new Player(50, 400, 20, 20);

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
  frameRate(60);
}

void draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  boxesUpdate();
  boxesCollision();
  entityUpdate();
  control();
  println(player.playerX + ", " + player.playerY);
  println(player.yVelocity + ", " + player.Gravity + ", " + player.onGround + ", " + player.canMoveDown);
}


//Box collision update method for when i add more boxes

void boxesCollision() {
  player.Gravity = true;
  player.canMoveUp = true;
  player.canMoveDown = true;
  player.canMoveLeft = true;
  player.canMoveRight = true;
  player.onGround = false;


  b.collision();
  b1.collision();

  if (player.Gravity) {
    player.playerY += player.yVelocity;
    player.yVelocity += gravity;
  }
}

//Along with another update method for the other parts of the boxes

void boxesUpdate() {
  b.update();
  b1.update();
}


//Entity update method to update players and for when i add NPCs and enemies

void entityUpdate() {
  player.update();
}

//Player class

class Player {
  private float playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight;
  private float yVelocity = 0;
  private float xVelocity = 0;
  private boolean canMoveRight, canMoveLeft, canMoveUp, canMoveDown;
  private boolean onGround, Gravity;
  Player(float X, float Y, float xSize, float ySize) {
    playerWidth = xSize;
    playerHeight = ySize;
    playerX = X;
    playerY = Y;
  }
  void update() {
    rect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: Maybe the tag should be `collision-detection` instead of `collision`?

Comment: We need a better description of your actual problem than just that "there is a bug somewhere". Describe your input, expected output, and actual output. Describe what is happening and what you expect it should be happening.

Comment: I won't to fix all the bugs in your code. But start with: `if (player.playerY >= ypos - player.playerHeight)` (focus on `>=`) at the end of `Box.collision` and  `player.yVelocity = 0 - jump;` (`-` instead of `+`) in  `control`.